# How to migrate between two keyrings in gnome-keyring

Tags: gnome, gnome-keyring

Due to some historic reasons I have 2 keyrings. I want to merge them - what is the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having talk to gnome-keyring developer on last desktop summit - it is not possible by GUI/command line (it is needed to program it).